# Why is the brython graphics stylesheet saying invalid syntax?

Tags: python, html, css, debugging

This code used to work. We did not change anything in the index.html page, yet suddenly, the graphics stopped displaying. This is infuriating.

I tried to inspect element and find out what was wrong, found the stylesheet was using invalid syntax somehow. However, the frame that the code creates still was created, and nothing else threw any errors.

[Link to code](https://github.com/Soldrion/E-DOS/tree/beta)

If you want, you can try to run it to find out what's wrong. I think it's CodeHS having another seizure. CodeHS can get really... weird sometimes.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

**yeah it was a javascript thing**

the error was on a completely different part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://static1.codehs.com/lib/brython/brython-3-11-1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://static1.codehs.com/lib/brython/brython-stdlib-3-11-1.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body onload="brython(1)">
    <canvas id="brython-canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    <script type="text/python" src="main.py"></script>
  </body>
```

there was no src/main.py